# Why will this not dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn about some of the C++ features and coded up a little test. However, when I try to compile, I get the following error (below). Why is this happening and what is the correct way to do it? I'm trying to cast a 32 bit pointer to an 8 bit pointer and print out the contents after the conversion.

> cast3.cpp:22: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'bigptr' (of type 'uint32_t*') to type 'uint8_t*' (target is not pointer or reference to class)

Code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void castme(uint8_t small[], int size);

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t *small;

    uint32_t big = 0x01234567;
    uint32_t *bigptr = &big;

    small = dynamic_cast<uint8_t *>(bigptr); // Line 22
    castme(small, sizeof(big));

    return 0;
}

void castme(uint8_t small[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%x\n",  small[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the compiler tells you the reason already: *(target is not pointer or reference to class)* so what exactly is that you dont understand here?

Comment: Of course I've googled and I marked your comment as unconstructive. From http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ "dynamic_cast can only be used with pointers and references to classes (or with void*). Its purpose is to ensure that the result of the type conversion points to a valid complete object of the destination pointer type." So, I should be able to convert between pointer types with this, right? 

Ed, sorry! I cleaned up the code a bit before posting but after the error. It's referring to the small = dynamic_cast... line.

Comment: Well, PlasmaHH, if you look at the code, both small and bigptr are indeed pointers. So seems to me the compiler is wrong.

Comment: @Maxthecat - Apart from using the wrong cast - the compiler is doing you a favour. Learn about type safety. IMHO ovoid casts - it usually implies something you are writing is wrong

Comment: @Maxthecat You seem to be quite, um, opinionated, I would say. You clearly haven't an idea about C++ basics, yet you are insisting that the compiler is wrong. **The compiler is never wrong.** (Okay, maybe some very smart or lucky/unlucky people manage to find a bug or two *very, **very** rarely.* You are not at their level of C++ knowledge, so be humble.)

Comment: @Maxthecat: Maybe you read the compiler output again. It doesn't stop at "pointer" it has four words following. Important are the last two.

Comment: @H2CO3: more importantly, when you are on that level, you rarely have to ask on SO ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yeah, not to mention that. ;)

Comment: Yes of course I read the output. The disconnect is in how that error message is written... When it says "not pointer or reference to class", you can interpret that two ways: 1) it must either be a pointer OR a reference to a class 2) it must be a pointer to a class or a reference to a class. I interpreted it in the former, which was not the intent and caused the disconnect. Still, the blatant sniping and attitude I got, right off the bat, was not warranted.

Comment: @Maxthecat: Jumping into conclusions that the compiler is wrong isn't an attitude? I haven't in the past 20 years seen anyone asking about what this compiler error means, and since you obviously did not understand it, it is unclear to me what part you did not understand exactly. If you don't want people to ask further questions about what it is that you want to have explained, maybe state so in the question.

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps I misinterpreted your tone @PlasmaHH. I read it with all of the acrid arrogance that the first comment implied. Perhaps you were just trying to be helpful and seek clarity? Edit: Although, if you could see what I was doing wrong, why not simply do what the others below did-- answer the question? It just smacks me of condescension

Comment: @Maxthecat: Because I believe in teaching people to fish, rather than to give them fish. Understanding error messages from compilers, debuggers etc. is a key to becoming a good developer in any language. Having an eureka moment by discovering it yourself is much more memorable. There are always people who will give you the fish anyways, so unless the question seems really hard/unintuitive, pointing the people into a direction where they can see everything needed to solve the problem will give them the choice: try to look again, or take the fish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` only works on classes with virtual member functions.  To cast raw pointer types between each other, you need `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong cast.  `dynamic_cast` only works with polymorphic class types, as it performs RTTI lookups at runtime.  You are not using polymorphic class types in your code.  To simply treat one pointer type as another pointer type, you need to use `reinterpret_cast` instead:

```
small = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(bigptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the code compile, you can do the following:

```
small = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(bigptr);
```

but I wouldn't do that, you should probably dereference the uint32_t pointer and then cast to the type you desire - there's no point casting to a uint8_t pointer in my mind.

ie.

```
uint8_t small_one = *bigptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reinterpret_cast. dynamic_cast has a different purpose.